# Need clarification on Function interface Type parameter in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I have a question on below piece of code using Function Interface. This converts a string to integer and the resultant integer back to String.

```
Function<String, Integer> toInteger = Integer::valueOf;
Function<String, String> backToString = toInteger.andThen(String::valueOf);
```

I am expecting the type parameters for backToString to be `<Integer, String>` instead of `<String, String>`. This is because, we are passing the integer result of the toInteger function to String::valueOf method.

Please explain.

Comment: The name is misleading: `backToString` should rather be `stringToIntegerAndBackToString`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`backToString` combines two functions :

First it passes its `String` input to `toInteger`, which returns an `Integer`.

Then that `Integer` is passed to `String::valueOf` which returns a `String`. Therefore `backToString` accepts a `String` and returns a `String`.

It can also be written as :

```
Function<String, Integer> toInteger = Integer::valueOf;
Function<Integer, String> toString = String::valueOf;
Function<String, String> backToString = toInteger.andThen(toString);
```